# Import data from free app to paid app

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, transfer

I developed a free application where you can save some user data. Now I developed a paid version without any ads and some other new features. I would like to have the data from the free app version transferred! How can I achieve this the best way?

Edit: you can save data of a played game with some infos (gamescore, playername, date etc) via NSKeyedArchiver. You can see all your saved data in a table view. I would like to see these stored data in the paid version as well, but how can I share the data? The given answers don't seem to be the straightest way!

Comment: Could you give a little more detail?  I'm assuming you're storing your data using SQLite, but is this an Android or an iPhone app?  Do the tables differ between paid and free?

Comment: @Jacinda: In the tags, it says it's an iPhone application.

Comment: @icktoofay - Sorry about that.  Editing comment.

Comment: And I have painfully gone over the time limit for editing... As icktoofay pointed out my inattention, this is an iPhone app.  I know how to specify that multiple applications can share a database on Android, but unfortunately don't know how to do the equivalent for an iPhone (I also have no idea, but suspect that it's a bit more complicated because apps have a more rigid sandbox on the iPhone).

Comment: @Maxi Buschmann can u please specify how you are storing data? using SQLite directly with queries? core data? or any other methods?

Comment: Sorry guys... i am storing the data with NSKeyedArchiver and the NSCoding protocol (archieveObject: toFile:). i am pretty new to iphone programming, hope you know what i mean ;)

Comment: Check out my answer, it covers other options as well

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this before but the way I can think of on how to do this is by first getting the location of your file (if it is Core Data, it is in your Documents folder) and then depending on how you want to import data either:

1. Attach the file to an email and have the user email himself and then open the file with your app
2. Send the file to a server, which then the user can access and download the file

A good starting point is Apple's documentation on [NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003660) and this [tutorial](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/data-file-management/iphone-file-system-creating-renaming-and-deleting-files.html). [This other one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/how-to-save-your-app-data-with-nscoding-and-nsfilemanager) deals with preparing for sharing files and custom extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Modify both apps to register for and handle custom URLs.  Have the paid app try to send a request URL to launch the free app.  If the free app handles the URL it can send data back using the paid app's URL.